# Specify NON-hardcoded path and filename in a scriptblock?

Tags: powershell

Ok I feel spechul for even asking, but I have tried several iterations of this and nothing has worked except hard coding the scriptname in the Scriptblock statement, which is unacceptable.

**Here is the code that works, hard coded, unacceptable....**

```
$Scriptblock = { C:\Scripts\Path1\ScriptName.ps1 -arguement0 $args[0] -arguement1 $args[1] }
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $Scriptblock -ArgumentList $argue0, $argue1 | Out-Null
```

**Ive tried this, and it doesn't work...**

```
$loc = (Get-Location).Path
Set-Location -Path  $loc
```

**And this....**

```
$rootpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path.Substring(0, ($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path).LastIndexOf("\"))
Set-Location -Path  $rootpath
```

**And this....**

```
$rootpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path.Substring(0, ($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path).LastIndexOf("\"))
$scriptFilename = $([string]::Format("{0}\ScriptName.ps1", $rootpath))
$sb = $([string]::Format("{0} -arguement0 $args[0] -arguement1 $args[1]", $scriptFilename))
$Scriptblock = { $sb }
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $Scriptblock -ArgumentList $argue0, $argue1 | Out-Null
```

**Nothing else has worked except the first code above with hardcoded path and script name - I know it has to be something stupid I am missing - help me fix stoopid please! ;-)**

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: Could you just pass the path as another argument to the scriptblock and use the call operator? `$sb = { param($path,$arg1,$arg2) & $path -argue0 $arg1 -argue1 $arg2 }`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Start a Job using that script with those arguements... However, the end user could place these scripts in any path, so I dont want hard coded paths.

Comment: But `ScriptName.ps1` is assumed to always be in the same folder as the script that starts the job?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Exactly! User has some freedom, but yes there are some constraints and assumptions..

Comment: @mikez Not sure I am totally following with the call operator? This is my first foray into Start-Job and ScriptBlock. I know my code examples above are not the least bit elegant and rather rudimentary, but I was trying to get things working first and optimize later.

Comment: I'm suggesting it as a possible solution, not an optimization. Although I'm not quite sure if the issue is that you can't find where the script is in general or maybe that you were not aware you could invoke a script whose path is within a variable (or maybe both?). How do the first two things you tried relate to the working example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your last example, this line:

```
$ScriptBlock = { $sb }
```

simply creates a scriptblock with a string inside it. Change it to:

```
$ScriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create($sb)
```

Comment: So that definitely looks like that is the way to go, thank you!! However, it doesnt seem to like the $args[0] and $args[1], when it converts it over from string toScriptblock they are showing simply as [0] and [1]... Do they need to be escaped, or handled differently somehow?

Comment: Use single-quotes instead of double-quotes in `[string]::format()`

Comment: Thanks for the quick and succinct responses, this works exactly how I wanted it to! If you are ever in Arizona I will buy you a beer!